JavaScript is not working when Thymeleaf th:field attribute is added
I am trying to add dollar signs to multiple fields using an event listener. However, attribute th:field will replace attributes value and name in the input tag.
I know the function is working because if I remove the th:field attribute, it works.
I'm unsure what I need to change and whether it is in the function or the input tag.
<form id="my-Form">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label th:for="amount"> Amount </label>
    <input th:field="${deposit.amount}" name="money_1" type="text" required>
  </div>

const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-Form');

myForm.addEventListener('input', e =>
  {
  if ( ['money_1','money_2'].includes(e.target.name)
    && !e.target.value.startsWith('$')
    ){
    e.target.value = "$" + e.target.value.trim();

    if (e.target.value === '$')
      e.target.value = '';
    }
  });

myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.clear();
  console.log('money_1 = ', myForm.money_1.value );
  console.log('money_2 = ', myForm.money_2.value );
  });


I will suggest you add a custom attribute or a class to identify the fields you want to process.
Then, don't rely on the name attribute instead use this custom attribute or class in your event listener.
I Made some changes to your code
<form id="my-Form">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label th:for="amount">Amount</label>
    <input th:field="${deposit.amount}" data-money-field="true" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label th:for="otherAmount">Other Amount</label>
    <input th:field="${deposit.otherAmount}" data-money-field="true" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-Form');

myForm.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('[data-money-field]') && !e.target.value.startsWith('$')) {
    e.target.value = "$" + e.target.value.trim();

    if (e.target.value === '$') {
      e.target.value = '';
    }
  }
});

myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.clear();
  const moneyFields = myForm.querySelectorAll('[data-money-field]');
  moneyFields.forEach(field => {
    console.log(`${field.name} = ${field.value}`);
  });
});

